# Geany: disk full, file truncated

Tags: debian, data-recovery, geany

I was working on a text file in Geany under Debian.
When I went for saving it, it said the disk was full.
So I freed some space and retried so save. This time it said the file on disk was newer.

I thought because it wasn't able to save so it wanted to restore the old content (it was fine to me). Instead it loaded a completely empty file! 
And I found no way to recover the previous content! Even "undo" didn't work.

I still have the editor opened: is there a way to recover the original content?

Answer (score 1):

I did not experienced the *disk is full* situation, but loosing data after a file reload in `geany` happened to me a few time in a `git` context.

Unfortunately I did not find a solution to retrieve data after a *geany file reload*.